# tastypie check for missing fields in json

Tags: django, field, tastypie, missing-data

I am creating an api using tastypie. Code is as follows. I have inspected code using ipdb.

```
class UserProfileResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'userprofiles'
        excludes = ['password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']
        filtering = {
            'username': ALL,
        }
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserProfileResource, 'user', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'users'

        list_allowed_methods = ['get','post']
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'patch', 'delete']
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json', 'jsonp', 'xml', 'yaml', 'html', 'plist'])
    def post_list(self, request, **kwargs):
        print 'post list method'
        mandatory_fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'city', 'pin']
        fields_apicall = request.GET.keys()
        #import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace();
        print request.POST
        if set(mandatory_fields).issubset(fields_apicall):
            print request.GET.keys()
            create_object = True
        else:
            print 'NO'
            err_dict = { 'error':'Mandatory Fields Missing.' }
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(err_dict))

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        print 'obj_create() '
        mandatory_fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'city', 'pin']
        fields_apicall =  bundle.data.keys()
        # import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace();
        if set(mandatory_fields).issubset(fields_apicall):
            bundle.obj = self._meta.object_class()
        else:
            err_dict = { 'error':'Mandatory Fields Missing.' }
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(err_dict))
```

I want to create nested user object, ie user object together with userprofile. For that I have to make sure all fields exists in the `json`. I tried overriding `hydrate()`,`dehydrate()`,and `post_list()` methods. Among these only `post_list()` get invoked on a post request.

I can check for `fields` in `request json` by overriding `post_list()` method but is this a good way to check for missing fields? I have googled and have gone through many SO posts but I didn't find any posts mentioning to override post_list() to check for missing fields some of them said to override `hydrate()`. Also is it necessary to override `obj_create()` method to create objects using tastypie?

Answer (score 0):

`obj_create()` seems like the best place to do it. Something like this should work:

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    mandatory_fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'city', 'pin']
    for field_name, field_object in self.fields.items():
        if field_name not in mandatory_fields:
            err_dict = { 'error':'Mandatory Fields Missing.' }
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(err_dict))
     super(SomeResource, self).obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs)
```